# How to access a joystick/gamepad from Mono/C# in Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, joystick, gamepad

I'm working on a robotics project using C# on a Raspberry Pi running Debian.  I've gotten a PS3 DualShock controller paired with the OS, so that it appears as joystick device /dev/input/js0.

Now I'd like to access the DualShock joysticks and buttons from C# code.  This appears to be harder (or at least more obscure) than I expected -- I've found references to OpenTK, which appears to be at least in a coma, if not dead; and XNA, which might do it but contains way more than I need (and I worry about about getting all that working on my RPi), as well as various other small wrapper projects that are less well supported.

As a newbie to Mono, C#, and Linux all at once, I'm in a bit over my head here... any suggestions as to the easiest/best way to read the DualShock state in this environment?

Comment: You could try my project which uses GLFW for input handling. I've never used GLFW to handle joystick input before, so we might both learn something from it. Here's the project (you could just copy/paste the glfw classes and natives to your code): https://github.com/antonijn/Pencil.Gaming

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking for a good cross-platform C# gaming library for other projects, and hadn't gotten very far with MonoGame.  Pencil.Gaming looks very interesting -- I'll give it a try.  I'll also let you know how it goes using it for my Raspberry Pi robot project!

Answer (score 1):

[Monogame](http://monogame.net/) is an open source implementation of XNA.  It is cross-platform, and does target Linux.  You could take a look at the framework's [Input Source Code](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/tree/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Input) to see how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

Mono gamepad events are typically polled. Below is a very basic code that demonstrates checking button "A" status.

```
GamePadState gamePadState;

gamePadState = GamePad.GetState((PlayerIndex)0); //Palyer indices are from 0-3, basically indicate the gamepad index

if (gamePadState.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
    //take action for button "A"
}
```

It is always a good idea to check gamepad connectivity status before accessing its buttons/triggers/thumbstick status values.

```
if (gamePadState.IsConnected)
{
    //check for button/trigger/thumbstick status
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at directinput, but thats for windows, there is however a now library that wraps it to c#. its called slimDX, perhaps you could get it to work

Comment: It's a wrapper for DirectX, a Windows-only technology; therefore, it wouldn't be useful to study for handling input on Linux.